# SPF: Difference between v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all and v=spf1 include:spf.google.com ~all

Tags: spf

What is the difference between

`v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`

and

`v=spf1 include:spf.google.com ~all`

(the first one is with underline character in front of the spf, the second one without)

Answer (score 15):

`spf.google.com` doesn't exist, while `_spf.google.com` contains a valid SPF record.

In other words: only the first line will actually work (as of now).

If you search DNS for _spf.google.com you get the following result:

> `_spf.google.com  IN  TXT v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all`

Google is using the _underscore addresses to hold particular DNS records. There is no particular significance to the character choice; it's just their naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

The "include" lets your spf record include another spf record, so it basically just points to a host entry.

The tool at http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html also performs lookup on includes, and will tell you in cleartext that the host spf.google.com does not exist.